# Entity Framework calling stored procedure and not getting result

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, dbcontext

I have called a stored procedure with EF code-first `DbContext` before, but I've tried several ways of doing it tonight and I am not getting any progress.

The stored procedure returns a 0 or 1

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[CustomerKeyChecker]
                          @ldccode = 'nstar'   --SET @listofCodes = 'CLP, UIC, NSTAR, NSTARB, NSTARC, PSNH'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

In my stored procedure, I have 1 incoming `varchar(12)` parameter, and then I do this:

```
SELECT @result = sign(charindex(' ' + @ldccode + ',', ' ' + @listofCodes + ','))
RETURN @result
```

So from executing it, that runs fine ...

Now from my C# Entity Framework code first, I either get Null or count of zero or that is will return many results...

poco

```
public class CustomerKey
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
}
```

1st attempt:

```
var param = new SqlParameter("@ldccode", key);
var result = _db.Database.SqlQuery<CustomerKey>("dbo.CustomerKeyChecker @ldccode", param).FirstOrDefault();
```

That returns null.

Next I try this

```
string sproc = "dbo.CustomerKeyChecker @ldccode=" + key;
var context = (_db as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
var result2 = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<CustomerKey>("exec " + sproc);
```

I keep trying to use `<string>`, `<int>`, `List<...>`, I would THINK that it should pass back the result of a single value of `int` or `string` ... I do not want to use EDMX, and I need to use this stored procedure. And I really don't want to resort to using old school ado.net command etc..

Is it that my stored procedure is not doing a `select * from ...` instead it calls `return`?

Or it is that my code is not mapped to poco and table entity?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it that my stored procedure is not doing a select * from ... instead it calls >return?

Yes.

My assumption - Jeremy started with EF code first and is open to a EF (database first) approach.

**REASON** - The template builder for EF (including v6) incorrectly sets the SP up as returning an INT containing the row count rather than the return value because it incorrectly calls the wrong ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction (found in the template-generated class YourDatabaseEntities that is the child of the DBContext).

Why wrong ExecuteFunction? - The result set incorrectly says the row count of changed rows rather than the return value or output parameters because it calls a different ExecuteFunction that discards the results. The flyover intellisense hint of the ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction says "Executes a stored procedure ….; *discards any results returned from the function; and returns the number of rows affected by the execution*" rather than the usual "Executes a stored procedure …. *with the specified parameters*".

**WHY -1 OR NULL**: I believe the SET NOCOUNT ON is causing the SP to return no count result and that Microsoft's ExecuteFunction returns that as error code.

**SP FIX**: 1) You have to comment out SET NOCOUNT ON if you have one. 2) You have to change SP to do the SELECT command as last statement instead of the RETURN command.

**CODE FIX**:

```
var spResults = context.LTM_Lease_DeleteSubFiles(...);  -- ... is your parameters
int? spReturnValueResult = spResults.FirstOrDefault();  -- first one is return value.
```

**SOLUTION FIX** - 1) After fixing SP, delete SP from Function Imports folder and the Data Store's SP folder. 2) Reload the SP into the EDMX by using the "Update Model from Database" 3) Rebuild all of your data project where the EDMX resides. 4) Exit Visual Studio and return. 5) Rebuild overall solution.

See:
[Entity Framework (Database first) has incorrect return result from stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46590413/entity-framework-database-first-has-incorrect-return-result-from-stored-proced)

Comment: In a stored procedure RETURN is intended to return a success or failure code to a calling TSQL statement, not to return data to a client.  The correct way to return data to a client is with a resultset or an output parameter.

Comment: Agreed.  But Jeremy Miller's core problem is he cannot know the success or failure code of a stored procedure.

Comment: And stored procedures should return an error to the client on failure, using THROW or RAISERROR if necessary.

Comment: @David, would love your feedback on my post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46590413/entity-framework-database-first-has-incorrect-return-result-from-stored-proced   and to continue or rehash this discussion there.